# Is it possible to handle shockwave objects in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, flash, flash-cs5, shockwave

I want to know, Is there any way to handle or control the shockwave objects in flash by using 'as3'? I know this is possible in 'Director' by using 'Lingo'. But I am not able to find any way or any articles from where i can get some idea about this. In the director, I've seen there is way to set some properties like camera position, light affects etc. with the shockwave objects. But I am not sure about the FLASH. Can it possible to use these type of properties with shockwave objects in flash, which could be controlled in action script3 ???

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such possibility in flash.
If you want complicated 3D in flash, I suggest you use something like [papervision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/)

Flash only has basic 3D transformation since version CS4, Director (ShockWave) have had advanced, hardware accelerated 3D for many years. But I think Director is in some sort of limbo and Idon't know if Adobe is going to continue to develop it.

The Flash player has also become faster and Actionscript more powerful, so I think that something like papervision3D may be a good alternative for the most part.

Also bare in mind that the Flash player is much more widespread than the ShockWave Player

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply Charlie. Actually, my client is going to provide me some shockwave 3d objects which I need to put in flash and control it (using camera, lights etc properties). I just need to tell him if it's possible by providing him any article to support my answer. It would be greatful if you could provide me with article link as well. Thanks once again!!

Comment: Im sorry but I don't think it is possible to add shockwave 3D objects in Flash.

Comment: Charlie's right. The Shockwave Player supports Flash playback, but the reverse isn't true. Shockwave rendered 3D through the GPU, but Flash doesn't have any capability like that - the best you could do would be to get ahold of the 3D models involved and display them in Flash with something like Papervision3D, as Charlie advises.

Comment: Thanks Charlie and Fenomas! I agree with you people. Can i get any document or link that will help me to convince my client?

Comment: If you can determine how the 3D objects were originally modeled, you may have options on how to export differently such that they are compatible with PaperVision3D.